# Does PWM (analogWrite()) need to be turned off before changing states of pins?

Tags: esp8266, arduino-esp8266, pwm

If I have:

```
analogWrite(4, 123);
```

Do I need to turn the PWM off like this:

```
analogWrite(4, 0);
```

If I'd like to set pin HIGH or LOW?

```
digitalWrite(4, HIGH);
```

In practice, changing pin HIGH/LOW works without turning PWM off but I'm encountering some unexpected behavior (my ESP8266 hangs) and I wonder if that could be the problem?

Comment: This is interesting. Can/did you create as simple test program to determine if this behavior is reproducible? (I don't have the ability to do it myself at the moment) Also, I found something similar on github [here](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/issues/2175)

Comment: I would make sure that you are using the most recent version of the arduino-esp8266 core -- just in case this is an old issue that has been fixed. I'll dig into this when I get a chance (or someone more knowledgeable than me will give an answer).

Answer (score 0):

On my NodeMCU, once you call `analogWrite` on a pin, any later calls to `digitalWrite` have no effect;  you're doomed to using `analogWrite(pin, 0)` or `analogWrite(pin, PWMRANGE)` which seems to work just fine.